# Bootstrap popover does not show when using Jquery custom trigger

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I am trying to create some kind of a value validation for my website. When user provides wrong number I want to show him a popover when he moves to another input box. The code for now is very simple, I want to show the popover every time user moves to another window so here is my code. It just doesnt work. When I tried something else like changing background into red one it works flawlessly.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control dl" placeholder="Długość" name="dl-{{forloop.counter}}" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.form-control.dl").blur(function(){
            $(this).popover({
                placement: 'top',
                content: 'Wrong VALUE!',
                title: 'ERROR',
            });
            $(this).popover('show');
        });

        $("input.form-control.dl").click(function() {
            $(this).popover('destroy');
        });
    });
</script>
```